# Linux and C, program errors

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to alter a bit a code to use 'threads' instead of 'forks'.   This is the code I have come up with, but there's an error message, and I'm unsure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 2 /* define the total number of processes we want */

/* Set global variable */
float total=0;

/* compute function just does something. */
int compute()
{
    int i;
    float oldtotal=0, result=0;
    /* for a large number of times just square root and square
    the arbitrary number 1000 */

    for(i=0;i<2000000000;i++)
    {
        result=sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(1000.0);
    }

    /* Print the result  should be no surprise */
    printf("Result is %f\n",result);

    /* We want to keep a running total in the global variable total */
     oldtotal = total;
     total = oldtotal + result;

    /* Print running total so far. */
    printf("Total is %f\n",total);

    return(0);
}

void* thread_procedure(void* param)
{
    int i = (int)param;

    /* give a message about the proc ID */
    printf("Process Id for process %d is %d\n",i,getpid());
    /* call the function to do some computation. If we used sleep
    The process would simply sleep. We do not want that */
    compute();

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    pthread_t thread[N];        
    float result=0;
    printf("\n"); /* bit of whitespace */

    /* We want to loop to create the required number of processes
    Note carefully how only the child process is left to run */
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        /* start new thread and catch it if it/one fails */
        j = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thread_procedure, (void*)i);

        if (j)
        {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /* joining with threads */
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

    /* nothing else to do so end main function (and program) */
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I receive, which I am not understanding

```
practical2b.c: In function ‘thread_procedure’:
practical2b.c:39:10: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size     
[-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  int i = (int)param;
          ^ 
practical2b.c: In function ‘main’:
practical2b.c:62:59: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size     
[-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   j = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thread_procedure, (void*)i);
                                                       ^
/tmp/cc9tHCVO.o: In function `main':
practical2b.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
practical2b.c:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The warning is actually fine; the error is failure to find the pthreads library. You have to add -pthread to the link line, and also add the library with -l. I don't know why GCC wants both, but it does.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: `-pthread` alone should be sufficient ("Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker."). One thing `-pthread` does that `-lpthread` doesn't is to define the `_REENTRANT` macro, which makes some functions reentrant. An easy way to compare them is to diff the (stderr) output from `gcc -v foo.c -pthread` and `gcc -v foo.c -lpthread`.

Comment: the compiler should also be outputting some other messages because two #includes are missing:  #include <sys/types.h> and  #include <unistd.h>  All the warnings should be enabled when compiling

Comment: there should be a compiler warning about the unused variable 'result' in the main() function

Comment: this line: 'j = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thread_procedure, (void*)i);' should be: 'j = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thread_procedure, (void*)&i);' in main() then in thread procedure, this line: 'int i = (int)param;' should be: 'int i = *(int*)param;'

Comment: the global variable 'total' will experience race conditions because the 'N' threads are all trying to write to that same variable.   This problem could be fixed via the use of a mutex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing all the errors/warnings raised by the compiler
and incorporating some of the earlier comments,
this is what the code would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 2 /* define the total number of processes we want */

/* Set global variable */
float total=0.0f;

/* compute function just does something. */
int compute()
{
    int i;
    float result=0.0f;
    /* for a large number of times just square root and square
    the arbitrary number 1000 */

    for(i=0;i<2000000000;i++)
    {
        result=sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(1000.0);
    }

    /* Print the result  should be no surprise */
    printf("Result is %f\n",result);

    /* We want to keep a running total in the global variable total */ 
    total += result;

    /* Print running total so far. */
    printf("Total is %f\n",total);

    return(0);
} // end function: compute


void* thread_procedure(void* param)
{
    int i = *(int*)param;

    /* give a message about the proc ID */
    printf("Process Id for process %d is %d\n",i,getpid());
    /* call the function to do some computation. If we used sleep
    The process would simply sleep. We do not want that */
    compute();

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    pthread_t thread[N];        
    printf("\n"); /* bit of whitespace */

    /* We want to loop to create the required number of processes
    Note carefully how only the child process is left to run */
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        /* start new thread and catch it if it/one fails */
        j = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thread_procedure, (void*)&i);

        if (j)
        {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /* joining with threads */
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

    /* nothing else to do so end main function (and program) */
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it still gets error messages works fine.

Comment: @elle_00: Did you mean to say that it still gets error messages? (It compiles with no error or warning messages for me.)

Comment: `(void*)&i` is not thread-safe, here, and the cast to `void *` is itself redundant.